# Why is `npm install` adding all these extra script files to my IntelliJ IDEA project directory?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, npm

As of yesterday, whenever I `npm install` in IDEA, all these extra script files (the red files) get added to my project directory.

[image: all these extra script files]

Here is what's in `uuid`:

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/node_modules/uuid/bin/uuid" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/node_modules/uuid/bin/uuid" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

and in `uuid.cmd`:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\uuid\bin\uuid" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\node_modules\uuid\bin\uuid" %*
)
```

It's annoying and it really clutters up my project. This just started happening and I do not remember changing any settings in IDEA. Why is this happening and/or how can I make it stop?

**Update:** I think this may have something to do with node/npm global settings but I'm not sure.

Comment: are those files a part of the modules being downloaded?

Comment: No, the modules themselves are being installed properly to the `./node_modules` directory, and they don't contain any scripts like that: [see here](https://i.imgur.com/8bxzpxQ.png)